# Exception when attempting to cast IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, ienumerable

I'm still in my first couple weeks of learning C# for a project, and I'm trying to properly implement the `IEnumerable` interface. I've read a number of tutorials/guidelines, but I still seem to be doing something incorrectly. I have a strong Java background, so I think some of my knowledge of Java generics is muddling my understanding how they work in C#.

A class that **I cannot alter** contains an instance variable:

`public IEnumerable<object> Items;`

And I'd like to provide it with an instance of my `SampleDataSource` class. This class acts as a storage container for a `List` of `MyObject` types:

```
    public class SampleDataSource : IEnumerable
    {
        public List<MyObject> Subjects { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerator<MyObject> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.Cast<MyObject>().GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

But when I attempt to cast *an instance* of this `SampleDataSource` class to an `IEnumerable<object>` using this code:

```
Items = (IEnumerable<MyObject>)App.SampleData;
```

I receive an exception:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource.SampleDataSource' to
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource.MyObject]'.

But I don't quite understand why - isn't my `SampleDataSource` properly acting as an `IEnumerable` that returns an enumerator containing `MyObject` types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't just implement the methods, but rather has to actually implement the interface.

In your case, it'd be better to just make your class implement the appropriate interface.

```
public class SampleDataSource : IEnumerable<MyObject>, IEnumerable
```

Otherwise, you can use something like [linfu](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/) to duck-type your class to the interface.

The other potential object is to use `OfType<T>` to handle this:

```
// returns enumerable of the items that are actually assignable to MyObject
IEnumerable<MyObject> values = theDataSource.OfType<MyObject>();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does it not properly implement the interface here: `SampleDataSource : IEnumerable`?

Comment: @craig It needs to implement `IEnumerable<MyObject>`

Comment: @craig Are you trying to get `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<MyObject>`?

Comment: Ah, that was indeed the issue, had to add a type declaration to the interface I was implementing. (In addition to implementing the `IEnumerable` interface w/o a type defined.) I am trying to assign an instance of this class to a variable that is expecting an `IEnumerable<object>` I'm still implementing your solution, but I'll be back in a second for the accept. :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is answered already, but I missed a simple explanation of the problem behind your question, so here goes:

The reason you cannot assign your `SampleDataSource` class to an `IEnumerable<object>` field is that `SampleDataSource` does not implement `IEnumerable<object>`.  While it does implement `IEnumerable`, that's not good enough, because `IEnumerable<object>` is a *subtype* of `IEnumerable`.

Because of interface covariance, you *will* be able to assign the class to the `IEnumerable<object>` field if it implements `IEnumerable<MyObject>`, provided that MyObject is in fact a reference type (i.e., a class).  That's only applicable to C# 4.0 and later, however.

Reed Copsey's answer doesn't mention that you could declare the SampleDataSource class thus, because `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`:

```
public class SampleDataSource : IEnumerable<MyObject>
```

Further, since you're just wrapping the contained collection, you would normally implement it thus:

```
public class SampleDataSource : IEnumerable<MyObject>
{  
    public List<MyObject> Subjects { get; private set; }  

    public IEnumerator<MyObject> GetEnumerator()  
    {  
        return Subjects.GetEnumerator();
    }  

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()  
    {  
        return GetEnumerator();  
    }  
}
```

This is questionable from an object-orientation perspective, though, since you're giving the public read-write access to the list.  (The fact that the setter is private means that the public can't reassign the list reference, but it doesn't prevent them from calling `Add` or `Remove` or `Clear` on the list.)

Another take on the object orientation question would be to ask: if a SampleDataSource *contains* a sequence of MyObjects, why would it also *be* a sequence of MyObjects?  Instead of doing this:

```
classICannotAlter.Items = (IEnumerable<object>)someSampleDataSourceInstance;
```

maybe you should be doing this:

```
classICannotAlter.Items = (IEnumerable<object>)someSampleDataSourceInstance.Subjects;
```